# Problemas al eliminar un archivo a través de un observer en laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tengo 3 tablas que están relacionado. Las tablas son las siguientes

```
Schema::create('cursos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
 
        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('descripcion');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();

        $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('modulos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('curso_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('curso_id')
                ->references('id')->on('cursos')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->string('name');

        $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('videos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('modulo_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('modulo_id')
                ->references('id')->on('modulos')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->string('name');
        $table->text('descripcion');
        $table->string('iframe');
        $table->string('file')->nullable();
        $table->string('slug')->nullable();


        $table->timestamps();
});
```

En la tabla videos estoy almacenando el link de unos archivos base. He creado, un observer, el cual verifica si se elimina algún registro de la tabla videos, y si se elimina un registro, también elimina el archivo.

El código del observer es este:

```
public function deleted(Video $video)
{
        
    $filePath = str_replace('storage', 'public', $video->file);
    Storage::delete($filePath);
    
}
```

El observer me funciona perfecto cuando elimino un registro de la tabla videos manualmente. Mi problema va cuando elimino los registros en cascada.

Si elimino un registro de la tabla cursos, se elimina por cascada los registros de la tabla módulos y los registros de la tabla videos, pero ignorara al observer y no me elimina los archivos base.

O es que el alcance del observer no funciona cuando se elimina en cascada y debería crear un observer para modulos y cursos que verifique cuando se elimine y de esa manera eliminar los archivos?

También probé utilizando el método deleting y no me funcionó

Comment: Intenta con `Storage::delete($video->file);`

Comment: es porque al momento de relacionar la tabla lo estas haciendo de uno a muchos en modulo y el video no esta haciendo la función que debería, si quieres eliminar los registros de la tabla videos tienes que relacionar de video uno a muchos en videos. intenta cambiar esto a traves del modelo

Comment: Sí, tendrías que crear un observer para cursos y módulos, pues ese onDelete cascade funciona a nivel base de datos, y el modelo Vídeo no es instanciado, entonces Eloquent nunca se entera de que se eliminó un registro en BD.